# Log all queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, logging

Is it possible for me to turn on audit logging on my mysql database?

I basically want to monitor all queries for an hour, and dump the log to a file.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/650238/684229

Comment: For readers benefit: Don't miss to read the question in the above comment.

Comment: You can refer my existing answer posted here http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62477/6037

Comment: To turn logging on/off **without restarting mysql**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678310/199364).

Answer (score 178, accepted):

UPDATE: NO LONGER VALID FOR MYSQL 5.6+

Start mysql with the --log option:

```
mysqld --log=log_file_name
```

or place the following in your `my.cnf` file:

```
log = log_file_name
```

Either one will log all queries to log_file_name.

You can also log only slow queries using the `--log-slow-queries` option instead of `--log`.  By default, queries that take 10 seconds or longer are considered slow, you can change this by setting `long_query_time` to the number of seconds a query must take to execute before being logged.

Comment: It should go without saying, but leaving this turned on in a production box winds up being non-entertaining very quickly. *g*

Comment: If you have trouble enabling logging in this manner, doublt-check that the mysql user can write to the appropriate file location.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `mysqld` changes to `/var/lib/mysql`, so unless you specify an absolute path, the file will end up there.

Comment: Is it possible to log queries over 1 particuarl db / table only?

Comment: @Temujin phpmyadmin has now a 'tracking' option for tables where you specify a log('version') and it will keep record of the queries affecting it with information about time and the whole query.

Comment: So you have to start/stop to change this setting?

Comment: general_log = on general_log_file=/path/to/query.log

Comment: This accepted answer should be deleted or edited to reflect the fact that it doesn't work with MySQL 5.6.+.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to log only queries that alternate the data, so no selects but updates, deletes etc?

Comment: none of the answers actually work for -all- queries. the only thing that gets logged are CORRECT queries (wether they have a result set or effect or not). queries that trigger syntax errors are NOT logged. therefore these logs are suitable for optimizing already bug-free code's performance, but not for figuring out what's going on if the resulting queries are not correct SQL syntax wise.

also the 2 tables 'created' already seem to ship with the default installation, at least on any machine i've tried it with. :P

Answer (score 281):

Besides what I came across here, running the following was the simplest way to dump queries to a log file without restarting

```
SET global log_output = 'FILE';
SET global general_log_file='/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_general.log';
SET global general_log = 1;
```

can be turned off with

```
SET global general_log = 0;
```

Comment: Absolutely love this, works for existing and new connections on the DB

Comment: There were some Statistics entries - not sure what those are but, otherwise, works really well.

Comment: For this to work your user must have the SUPER privilege which is a global DB privilege and so cannot be limited to specific schemas or tables: `GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user1@localhost`

Comment: I'd upvote that more than once if I could, I have a bookmark pointing here :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: better than the accepted answer,  starting mysql with mysqld is a bit clumsy in many situations.  This is useful in the most common case where you want to do some quick debugging and then switch it off.

Comment: Status update: this is still one of my favorite bookmarks :)

Comment: Oh, look who's visiting again :) If we ever meet I'm so gonna pay you beer/coffee/lunch!

Comment: this doesn't do anything, nothing gets written to the log

Answer (score 266):

(**Note**: For mysql-5.6+ this won't work. There's a solution that applies to mysql-5.6+ if you [scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql#answer-25080306) or [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25080306/535759).)

If you don't want or cannot restart the MySQL server you can proceed like this on your running server:

- Create your log tables on the `mysql` database

```sql
  CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
   `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                          ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `query_time` time NOT NULL,
   `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
   `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
   `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log'
```

```sql
  CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
   `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                          ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'
```

- Enable Query logging on the database

```sql
SET global general_log = 1;
SET global log_output = 'table';
```

- View the log

```sql
select * from mysql.general_log
```

- Disable Query logging on the database

```sql
SET global general_log = 0;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true for every version of MySQL (I'm on 5.5), but I didn't have to create the tables. I followed the same advice minus creating the tables, which is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/678310/135101

Comment: Maybe it was already created for one or other reason, @TylerCollier

Comment: It should be noted that the `CREATE TABLE` commands should (if the tables do not already exist) be executed on the `mysql` database, not on any user-created databases. Perhaps the SQL statements could be updated to reflect that.

Comment: For viewing the log `SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log order by (event_time) desc` will do better. just saying.:-)

Comment: Don't agree with *note* - with server version  5.6.37 works fully correctly. Thanks.

Comment: To know if logging is enable : SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'general_log';

Answer (score 169):

Top answer doesn't work in mysql 5.6+. Use this instead:

```
[mysqld]
general_log = on
general_log_file=/usr/log/general.log
```

in your my.cnf / my.ini file

**Ubuntu/Debian**: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
**Windows**: c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.x
**wamp**: c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\my.ini
**xampp**: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini.

Comment: If you have used it, can you tell me the performance impact of the above,  and would it be wise to enable logging this way?

Comment: Ramesh performance impact seems to be around 5-15% decrease in performance. More info here https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/02/10/impact-of-logging-on-mysql%E2%80%99s-performance/

Comment: I don't understand why Mysql 5.6 doesn't allow log file to be set from queries ? How to log all queries in MySQL 5.6 and later when you don't have access to server directory tree but only `phpMyAdmin` ?

Comment: restart mysql service from xampp control panel after these changes.

Comment: This worked for me in my local Xampp Apache environment, but I still had to turn the logging on via phpMyAdmin.  Also, it couldn't locate the file in the /usr/log folder, nor would it create it, but it worked just fine as `general_log_file=filename.log`

Comment: Don't forget to restart MySQL server 'sudo systemctl restart mysqld`

Answer (score 60):

Enable the log for table

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
mysql> SET GLOBAL log_output = 'table';
```

View log by select query

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log
```

If there's too much queries, truncate the table:

```
TRUNCATE table mysql.general_log;
```

Comment: is there a wildcard to log all tables? (there are quite a lot :C)

Comment: Thanks, this setting was very useful for me as I could not take down the mysql-server. I also want the log to appear in the log-table

Comment: This table has a column called 'thread_id' that helps to distinguish to bifurcate the queries issues in a particular session, as against the dump of all the queries issued to the entire database, which is what otherwise you get it for your SELECT query on the mysql.general_log table.

Answer (score 22):

Quick way to enable MySQL General Query Log without restarting.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/var/www/nanhe/log/all.log';
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

*I have installed mysql through homebrew, mysql version : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.*

Answer (score 8):

For the record, general_log and slow_log were introduced in 5.1.6:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log-destinations.html

> 5.2.1. Selecting General Query and Slow Query Log Output Destinations
>
> As of MySQL 5.1.6, MySQL Server provides flexible control over the
> destination of output to the general query log and the slow query log,
> if those logs are enabled. Possible destinations for log entries are
> log files or the general_log and slow_log tables in the mysql
> database

Answer (score 6):

OS / mysql version:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin Raphaels-MacBook-Pro.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 21 20:07:40 PDT 2018; root:xnu-3248.73.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ mysql --version
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23, for osx10.8 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Adding logging (example, I don't think `/var/log/...` is the best path on Mac OS but that worked:

```
sudo vi ./usr/local/mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64/my.cnf

[mysqld]
general_log = on
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysqld_general.log
```

Restarted Mysql

Result:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysqld_general.log
181210  9:41:04    21 Connect   root@localhost on employees
           21 Query /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.47 ( Revision: fe1903b1ecb4a96a917f7ed3190d80c049b1de29 ) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@collation_server AS collation_server, @@collation_connection AS collation_connection, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_buffer_length AS net_buffer_length, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@query_cache_size AS query_cache_size, @@query_cache_type AS query_cache_type, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@tx_isolation AS transaction_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout
           21 Query SET NAMES latin1
           21 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
           21 Query SET autocommit=1
           21 Query SELECT USER()
           21 Query SELECT USER()
181210  9:41:10    21 Query show tables
181210  9:41:25    21 Query select count(*) from current_dept_emp
```