# How to increase temporary table size in a my.cnf file on macOS?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm getting the following error when trying to query a large amount of data from my home project database:

```
Error Code: 1114. The table '/var/tmp/#sql73_198dd_af' is full
```

The query is pulling nearly all the data from 5-6 tables that have a combined on disk size of about 3Gb.

I gather from reading around that I need to amend the `my.cnf` file to increase the size of my temporary tables. I'm a little uncertain as to what configuration I need to add as I'm a long way away from being an expert on mysql. The `my.cnf` file was pretty sparse to begin with but with a couple of additional lines it now looks like this:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
tmp_table_size = 12G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
max_heap_table_size = 12G
```

I've also specified the location of the config file in System Preferences:

[image]

However, after restarting mysql and restarting my machine I'm still getting the same error when I try to run the query. Additionally, when I go to `Server` > `Options File` in Workbench I get a screen that says `Location of MySQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified`. Furthermore the `Find` text entry box, where I think I should be able to find and set the location, is greyed out.

It would appear I have an issue with mysql not reading my config file - could anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm also aware that I may not be adding the right settings to the config file. This should probably be the subject of another post but any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Last, how would I find out what settings my current instance of mysql is using? I've tried running `SELECT @innodb_buffer_pool_size` from Workbench but I get a null result. I'm not sure if I'm not running the right command or it actually is null (unlikely!).

I'm running mysql 8.0.26 on a MacBook Pro with Big Sur 11.6 and 16G of RAM.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Update:

I've now worked out how to point Workbench at the `my.cnf` file. You can do this via `Database` > `Manage Connections...` > `System Profile` > `Configuration File:`. However, I can't actually find any of the settings like `innodb_buffer_pool_size`! The query also still doesn't run after a restart of mysql.

Now I reckon one or more of the following things could be happening:

1. I haven't added enough to the config file to fix the temp table issue
2. My `12G` settings aren't enough to run the query
3. mysql still isn't reading the config file

Could someone provide me with any pointers?

Comment: Maybe this might help
https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/17/mysql-disk-space-exhaustion-for-implicit-temporary-tables/

Comment: There is no any restriction for temporary table size in MySQL. Check for available disk space...

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - thanks. I've added in `max_heap_table_size` but the query still won't run. The article also refers to storing temp tables on disk but doesn't actually explain what settings to change to do this.

Comment: @Akina - thanks. I thought temp tables were supposed to be stored in RAM? On the HDD side I have 79Gb of free space so pretty sure that's not the bottleneck...

Comment: I guess you cannot know how big the tmp table will be. It may vary on the complexity of your query. So, as mentioned in the article, if you have a query with order or group by clauses this table can complete fill your RAM.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - exactly! How can I check the settings in the `my.cnf` file have taken effect? I've tried running SELECT @innodb_buffer_pool_size from Workbench but I get a null result. I'm not sure if I'm not running the right command or it actually is null (unlikely!).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493722/mysql-command-for-showing-current-configuration-variables
you musst query for the variables

Comment: At the end I would be interesting of the use csse to query 3GB of data in one query. What is the goal of this?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - I need to extract it to import into and then train a machine learning model

Comment: why don't you use mysqldump then?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - I thought that was just for exporting single or multiple tables to SQL files. I see that you can export to CSV which could work however I can't find anywhere that explains the syntax to do a dump from a query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935556/mysql-dump-by-query

Comment: @Shadow - thanks. This seems to be more slightly focussed on exporting whole tables. There is one post that uses `OUTFILE` which I've managed to get working but this also fails with the error: `Error Code: 1114. The table '/var/tmp/#sqla79_9_16' is full`

Comment: Nope, you can use mysql cli to export query results as well as described in the accepted answer. You can substitute any query in place of select * from mytable...

Comment: I also have this problem, my DB is 400GB and my disk has more than 600GB of free space, yet I am getting this error... no idea why