# MySQL: Select the last executed queries

Tags: mysql

How to select the last executed queries in MySQL?

Comment: Would you mind giving us a few more details, please? Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand the question

Comment: I know that in oracle we have a "select" that returns the queries history. Is there something similar in MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the General Query Log.

Edit:  Duplicate question.  [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

If the general query log is enabled, then you can use `tail` to see the most recent queries executed on your server.

If the general query log is disabled, there is no way to do this.

If the binary log is enabled you can see the most recent insert/update/delete queries in there, but not selects.