# SQL command to display history of queries

Tags: mysql

I would like to display my executed sql command history in my MYSQL Query Browser. What is the sql statement for displaying history?

Comment: sounds like a repost of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Answer (score 213):

try

```
 cat ~/.mysql_history
```

this will show you all mysql commands ran on the system

Comment: well not *all*,  suppression occurs for some that contain strings like "password".

Comment: It's also not usually up-to-date with your open MySQL CLI so you're likely to have to `exit` MySQL then read the file.

Comment: This only shows commands executed by the user that is logged in.

Comment: How to do this in windowss

Comment: It is there a possibility that other commands are suppressed or that they are unordered? And, does the log update it self in real time?

Comment: This is great for ones run by a user, but what about ones run by other programs running, such as by PHP scripts on a webserver?

Comment: This is only for MySQL clients I believe. If any application running the query on MySQL that is not showing here. What is the option to get that?

Answer (score 41):

For MySQL > 5.1.11 or MariaDB

1. `SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';`
2. `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`
3. Take a look at the table `mysql.general_log`

If you want to output to a log file:

1. `SET GLOBAL log_output = "FILE";`
2. `SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "/path/to/your/logfile.log"`
3. `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`

As mentioned by jeffmjack in comments, these settings will be forgetting before next session unless you edit the configuration files (e.g. edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, then restart to apply changes).

Now, if you'd like you can `tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log`

[More info here: Server System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log)

Comment: Just some clarification to the above:

The copy-paste commands here are for a single session of MySQL, e.g. you can enter these from the interactive MySQL command line. If you want them to be a permanent feature of your MySQL instance, you need to put those commands in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and restart the MySQL service.

Comment: Also note that logging will stop if `/path/to/your/logfile.log` is deleted, until you execute `SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "/path/to/your/logfile.log";` again (or maybe restart the session if you edited the configuration ?).

Comment: for further clarification of @jeffmjack 's answer, the format of the commands in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is of the form `general_log=on`

Answer (score 41):

You 'll find it there

```
~/.mysql_history
```

You 'll make it readable (without the escapes) like this:

```
sed "s/\\\040/ /g" < .mysql_history
```

Answer (score 22):

(Linux) 
Open your Terminal `ctrl+alt+t`
run the command

```
 cat ~/.mysql_history
```

you will get all the previous mysql query history enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

@GoYun.Info answer but with python 3

```
cat ~/.mysql_history | python3 -c "import sys; print(''.join([l.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape') for l in sys.stdin]))"
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `~/.myslgui/query-browser/history.xml`
here you can find the last queries made with `mysql_query_browser`
(some days old)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the history from `~/.mysql_history`. However the content of the file is encoded by `wctomb`. To view the content:

```
shell> cat ~/.mysql_history | python2.7 -c "import sys; print(''.join([l.decode('unicode-escape') for l in sys.stdin]))"
```

Source:[Check MySQL query history from command line](https://it.goyun.info/2020/05/check-mysql-query-history-from-command.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can look at the query cache: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3110171/MySQLs-Query-Cache.htm but it might not give you access to the actual queries and will be very hit-and-miss if it did work (subtle pun intended)

But MySQL Query Browser very likely maintains its own list of queries that it runs, outside of the MySQL engine.  You would have to do the same in your app.

Edit: see dan m's comment leading to this: [How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql) looks sound.