# View SQL executed by MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using wordpress and I want to see all SQL being executed at the back-end. Do you guys any good tool which can be used to view any SQL executed by MySQL??

Comment: i think all queries get logged.

Comment: Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn on query logging. Here is a blog article that describes how to do it in detail: [MySQL Query Logging](http://www.redips.net/mysql/query-logging/).

To enable General query log add log line under the mysqld section in /etc/my.cnf configuration file and restart MySQL server.

> log=/var/log/mysqld.log

Many Linux distributions (like Fedora) come with created /var/log/mysqld.log file. Just be sure that mysqld.log file exists and mysql user has permissions to write. If you need to create a log file, use these commands:

```
# create mysqld.log file 
bash> touch /var/log/mysqld.log
# set owner and group owner for the mysqld.log file 
bash> chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysqld.log
```

To see the logs use this command

```
bash> tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Try doing it correctly.

Comment: yes, it works, I made an error while modifying