# php mysql left join syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, left-join

hello i have some error , i can't see it but members who visit site , tell me there ir an error

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT

m.member_id as member_id,
m.member_group_id as member_group_id,
m.members_display_name as members_display_name,
m.email as email,
m.joined as joined, 
m.member_login_key as member_login_key,
m.msg_count_new as msg_count_new,

p.pp_thumb_photo as pp_thumb_photo,
p.pp_photo_type as pp_photo_type

FROM        ".$forum_prefix."members m
LEFT JOIN   ".$forum_prefix."profile_portal p ON p.pp_member_id = m.member_id

WHERE m.member_id = ".$id."
") or die(mysql_error());
```

and error

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 17
```

Comment: What are the values of `$forum_prefix` and `$id` that give rise to this error?

Comment: What does your string concatenated evaluates to ? Can't you write that in a debug file or something ? I highly suspect you have `WHERE m.member_id = ` or a similar problem...

Comment: what are the possible value of `$forum_prefix`?

Comment: $forum_prefix and $id work's fine , 17 line are at m.msg_count_new as msg_count_new,

Comment: Please put [the last query received by your mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Comment: try single quotes for ".$forum_prefix." , ".$forum_prefix." and ".$id."

Comment: "near '' at line 17": The 17 line is the last line: `WHERE m.member_id = ".$id.""`. So I guess $id is empty.

Comment: yes , $id was empty tnq guy's

Answer (score 0):

```
$forum_prefix = "table_name";// put table name here.its empty in your code
$id = 2;//put your id here and check
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT

m.member_id as member_id,
m.member_group_id as member_group_id,
m.members_display_name as members_display_name,
m.email as email,
m.joined as joined, 
m.member_login_key as member_login_key,
m.msg_count_new as msg_count_new,

p.pp_thumb_photo as pp_thumb_photo,
p.pp_photo_type as pp_photo_type

FROM        ".$forum_prefix."members m
LEFT JOIN   ".$forum_prefix."profile_portal p ON p.pp_member_id = m.member_id

WHERE m.member_id = ".$id."
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: don,t think so , that is not a problem

Comment: You forgot a `.` after table_name. This will evaluate to `FROM table_namemembers m` and `LEFT JOIN table_nameprofile_portal p`

Answer (score 0):

- The `line 17` is the last line of your query.
- The only thing in this line is

  ```
  WHERE m.member_id = ".$id."
  ```
- The message error is `““` (empty string). This is a symptom of a "truncated" query.

So, the error is in your php code because the `$id` var is not set.