# LinqPAD doesn't show the SQL query when using mysql

Tags: mysql, linqpad

I am using latest linqPad 4.43.05 and connecting to Entity Framework POCO assmebly.
everything works great but the SQL tab doesnt show me the SQL Syntax

How can i make it work?

Comment: If the SQL doesn't show automatically there is not a lot you can do. I just tested with the latest LINQPad against an MSSQL database and the SQL output shows as normally. Have you considered filing a bug report with the developer of the MySQL driver?

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework itself provides no hooks for obtaining SQL traces, so LINQPad patches the standard DbProvider for SQL Server in memory to work around this. If you're not using a standard SQL connection string, or if you're instantiating the SQLConnection yourself, this feature will be bypassed.

Answer (score 3):

You can output the SQL in LINQ Pad using the following the ToTraceString method:

```
var q = (the linq query);

((ObjectQuery)q).ToTraceString().Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the last query executed via the mysql log.
It's a little tricky, but it works, look at this:
[How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)