# Find last query executed time in sql and mysql and pgsql from java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm in the need of last query executed time in mysql/sql/pgsql using query ... How can I get it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql

Comment: Why did you tag this with Postgres if you are using MySQL?

Comment: edited, i just want it for pgsql also

Answer (score 1):

MySql generates a log of logs including query log. Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) for details where the log is located and how to configure it. Now you can open the file and find any query including the last one.

Comment: Thanks, but i just need to know by executing query