# MySQL Database Hacked, how can I tell which rows were affected?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that was compromised. It's a very big content table and I don't know if any of the rows were altered. Is there a way in MySQL to see which rows were edited and when?

Comment: Play it safe, restore from a backup.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: I recommend that you implement some form of (text) logging for all non-trivial INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE DB operations committed by each application which implements any such access to your RDBMS.

Implemented properly this would allow you to reconstruct all (non-trivial) transactions to your DB for situations such as this.  It can also facilitate auditing.

(Trivial transactions might include any sorts of data changes that you would never care to re-construct or audit, such as transient cookies and other disposable or derivative state).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was compromised by injection you have to crawl through HTTP server's access log. MySQL has a query logging ability but it's "always" disabled since it seriously slows down the server. Otherwise: No.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [The General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) to track down the queries if its not turned off. For future you can use this steps mentioned in answer to set the query log [How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql).