# Mysql general logs not showing database name

Tags: mysql, database, general-log

I want to use the mysql general logs to list down all the queries executed on my specific database. I see that the database name is mentioned only when the command type is 'Connect'.

In the post below, one of the comments is based on the assumption that the user_host column in general_log, contains the database name
[mysql general query log for a specific database or user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573199/mysql-general-query-log-for-a-specific-database-or-user)

In my machine the user_host appears as 'user_name[user_name]@[127.0.0.1]' instead of 'user_name[database_name]@[127.0.0.1]'.

Is there any configuration which I need to set, so that the user_host shows the database name also.

Thanks
VJN