# Mysql query logging, with execution time, and number of returned results for select queries

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm debugging an issue where sql select query sometimes doesn't return results when it should. I have no idea if the problem lies within the plugin I'm using, libmysql library, or the mysql database itself. So - I'd like to log all queries on database level, and log the number of rows returned. [I enabled general query log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql), but it only stores the queries executed. Is there way to log execution time and number of rows returned as well? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your MySQL version additional information can be logged to the slow log.
Including rows_examined and rows_sent.

For example, see [Percona's additions to the slow log](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.1/diagnostics/slow_extended.html?id=percona-server%3afeatures%3aslow_extended_51&redirect=2)

Comment: That's a good start, but the long_query_time minimal limit is 1. The queries aren't slow (at most 0.8 ms), they just tend to lose results. Is there some hack to consider all queries as "slow"?

Comment: long_query_time can be 0, effectively logging all queries. Even community version of MySQL since 5.1.something supports that

Comment: "Beginning with MySQL 5.1.21, the minimum is 0, and the value can be specified to a resolution of microseconds" - How did I miss that? Thanks!