# MySQL Corruption when Java Application Terminates

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, exception, dao

When i run my java application which accesses a MySQL database sometimes when the application terminates with an exception a couple rows of my table i was working with are deleted. I am only using SELECT on the table in my code. What could cause this to happen? Connection leak? If so whats the best way to diagnose and fix the problem?

Comment: Have you checked what queries were run last on MySQL?

Comment: No. Using Navicat for my DB manager. Not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql

Comment: Yeah i found out how. Will report back next time it happens.

Comment: Sounds like a transaction rollback, where those rows inserted by the application and not yet committed?

Comment: Nope all i do from this database table is select the rows and process them. Never insert back into the db the entire row. I do however update a column in the row. I think this is where my error is happening.