# Wamp , Mysql service stopped after browsing my local website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wamp

I use Wamp to create my test websites , today i face a problem that i not face before 
when i start wamp -> icon become green , everything is fine .
Once i browse my local website , http://localhost/mywebsite , Wamp Icon changed to orange and mysql service stopped automatically , and the page display this error , "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded " , i changed this time from php.ini and set it to 600 , but still the same problem , page take long time to load and then didn't loaded yet

i use wordpress  and also when i open wordpress control panel same problem happened , 
i though that happened because of huge data in my DB , i remove all records , and still the same problem , any idea ?

NOTE:i have no infinity loop .

below is last records from MySQL log file

```
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 403698529
2015-01-17 23:44:52 4768 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database... 
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 
                     37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 
                     55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 
                     73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 
                     91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99  
InnoDB: Apply batch completed 
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 45110, file name mysql-bin.000040 
2015-01-17 23:44:52 4768 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active. 
2015-01-17 23:44:52 4768 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start 2015-01-17
23:44:53 4768 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number
 403698529 2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin 
2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [Note] Starting crash recovery... 
2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
wampmysqld: File '.\mysql-bin.000001' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory) 
2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '.\mysql-bin.000001', errno 2) 
2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [ERROR] Could not open log file 
2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306 
2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [Note] IPv6 is available. 
2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::'; 
2015-01-17 23:44:53 4768 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.   
2015-01-17 23:44:54 4768 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events 
2015-01-17 23:44:54 4768 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections. 
Version: '5.6.12-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: it could be your RSS feeds plugin , turn it off if it's on

Comment: i don't use RSS plugin

Comment: Well it looks like somehow you crashed MySQL and it is attempting to recover that database. However it is failing the recovery because.. I guess you have deleted some of the mysql-bin files specifically `mysql-bin.000001`. Maybe you should [start here, looking in the manual for how to recover an INNODB Database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-backup.html)

Answer (score 0):

[How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Turn on your query log, then look to see if it is a hung query.  You can also do this from phpmyadmin while the server is still running.

Comment: thanks lance , I check mysql log file ,but i have no idea - Check my post update please

Comment: here is what I would do: backup the site, and then edit site to remove the template - test, then plugins -then test, then code.