# Using Wordpress RSS into app for fetching content can effect my wordpress site performance?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have been using wordpress RSS feed in one of my app which has over 3000 downloads. From the past few time I see my wordpress getting crashed to often and I get database errors like database timeout or error establishing database connection.

Is it because the app is calling wordpress feeds to often due to the large number of downloads.

The website url is http://sarkarijobmilegi.in

Comment: What size server are you running this one? What's your RDBMS? Is it on the same server? How many visitors/hits are you getting per day? Any spikes in visitors when you have this problem? There are so many variables here before you could even begin to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Answer to my third question: Yes, the database is on localhost. So: Is the database up? Is the username/pass correct in your wordpress config? Does it only go down intermittently?

Comment: I am using VPS Server from dreamhost which Includes: 60 GB RAID6 SSD Drive Setup, 4 GB Burstable RAM Usage, 2 TB Data Transfer. I have other websites as well on the same server. But the service provider informed me that the same website mentioned above is calling too much of SQL queries which is causing such problems.

The server is Aparche. Yes the database is on same server. I am getting over 20,000 - 30,000 Visits per day. I havent noticed if there is an spike in visitors that is causing it but when I do something that runs a sql command i face this problem like post update.

Comment: You may want to turn on logging on your mysql server so you can see the SQL being submitted to the server. [Check out this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql) for a good way to do that. Given your issue, I would suggest going with the "File" output. This will increase the demand on your database, so best to just have it on for a bit and then shut it off and see what you get. Then you can troubleshoot from there.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I was in Wordpress. Perhaps there is an RSS plugin or something that will generate static HTML instead of having your RSS requests hit the database (if your RSS app is the problem). Or perhaps you can have your App poll your site for the last blog entry and if it's greater than the previous RSS pull, then perform the pull. Likewise, you may have luck sticking your site behind a CDN like Cloudflare that will cache your content and lessen the load on your site, and the DB behind it. At any rate, there's more than a few options available... depending.

Comment: Id User Host db Command Time State Info
14063 statusnm_whatsap localhost statusnm_whatsapp Sleep 0  NULL
14064 sarkarij_new localhost sarkarij_new Sleep 0  NULL
14066 sarkarij_new localhost sarkarij_new Sleep 0  NULL
14067 sarkarij_new localhost sarkarij_new Sleep 0  NULL
14068 sarkarij_new localhost sarkarij_new Sleep 0  NULL
14069 sarkarij_new localhost sarkarij_new Sleep 1  NULL
14070 sarkarij_new localhost sarkarij_new Sleep 0  NULL
14071 sarkarij_new localhost sarkarij_new Sleep 1  NULL
14072 sarkarij_new localhost sarkarij_new Sleep 1  NULL

Comment: That's just a lot of `SLEEP` which is fine. It just means that mysql is awaiting a command. So this little bit shows no activity. Perhaps turn on your logging and wait for your website to have DB issues. Then you can check out what's going on that caused it die.

Comment: I have installed WP Super Cache to minimize the SQL querries on the database lets see if it helps else will try cloudflare