# Query builder in Codeigniter generates correct SQL statement, but executing the query leads to incorrect results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter query builder to generate my SQL query. On running the query through `$this->db->get()`, the result consists of null values in a PK column, which is incorrect (evidence is provided below).

On viewing the generated SQL query, through `$this->db->get_compiled_select()`, the SQL query is confirmed as properly created. Furthermore, I tested the SQL query in 2 different ways:

1. By executing directly on MySQL. The result obtained is correct and does not contain null values in any PK columns.
2. By running through Codeigniter again, but this time using `$this->db->query('SQL query string')`. Again, th result obtained is correct and does not contain null values in any PK columns.

In addition to this, I logged the queries being sent to MySQL by turning on general query log as described in [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql). In all 3 cases (that is, running query through query builder class, running query directly through MySQL command line, and running query through codeigniter, but using $this->db->query()), the SQL query received by MySQL is the same.

Given the above evidence, am I right in arriving at the conclusion that this is a bug in Codeigniter Query Builder Class? Or am I missing some other source of error?

Given below are my table contents, and the source code:

**Restaurant Table:**

```
RestaurantID  Name  
1             Awesome Bar
2             Disco Deewaane
3             Decibel Disco
4             Basswaala Bar
```

**Outlet Table (column RestaurantID is FK to Restaurant Table):**

```
OutletID RestaurantID Name             Address          Phone                  Latitude Longitude   
1        1 [->]       Awesome Bar      Roop Nagar       9837464231             0        0
2        1 [->]       Aww Bar          Prem Bhavan      8461232871             0        0
3        2 [->]       Disco Deewaane   Gali Number 420  8372313874             0        0
4        2 [->]       Decibel Disc     Excuse Me Please 9833346521             0        0
5        3 [->]       Disc Dec         Roop Nagar       8375643111             0        0
6        4 [->]       Bass Down Low    Prem Bhavan      9988843511             0        0
7        4 [->]       Baby ka Bass Bar Gali Number 420  8883741234             0        0
8        4 [->]       Basswaala Bar    Excuse Me Please 9993741236,8843621439  0        0
```

**OutletTable table (OutletID is FK to Outlet table):**

```
TableID OutletID TableNumber Capacity Smoking Available     
1       1 [->]   1           6        0       1
2       1 [->]   2           6        0       1
3       1 [->]   3           8        1       1
4       2 [->]   1           4        1       1
5       2 [->]   2           4        1       1
6       2 [->]   3           6        1       1
7       3 [->]   1           6        1       1
8       3 [->]   2           6        1       1
9       3 [->]   3           4        1       1
10      3 [->]   4           5        1       1
11      1 [->]   z           10       1       0
```

**Query in question:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Restaurant` 
RIGHT JOIN `Outlet` ON `Restaurant`.`RestaurantID` = `Outlet`.`RestaurantID`
LEFT JOIN `OutletTable` ON `Outlet`.`OutletID` = `OutletTable`.`OutletID`
```

**Correct result from query:**

[image]

**Result actually obtained when using Query Builder Class**

Note the from **index 11 onwards**, the OutletID is not correctly reported and **null is obtained** (which is why it is shown as blank in print_r output below):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 1
            [Name] => Awesome Bar
            [OutletID] => 1
            [Address] => Roop Nagar
            [Phone] => 9837464231
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 1
            [TableNumber] => 1
            [Capacity] => 6
            [Smoking] => 0
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 1
            [Name] => Awesome Bar
            [OutletID] => 1
            [Address] => Roop Nagar
            [Phone] => 9837464231
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 2
            [TableNumber] => 2
            [Capacity] => 6
            [Smoking] => 0
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 1
            [Name] => Awesome Bar
            [OutletID] => 1
            [Address] => Roop Nagar
            [Phone] => 9837464231
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 3
            [TableNumber] => 3
            [Capacity] => 8
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 1
            [Name] => Awesome Bar
            [OutletID] => 1
            [Address] => Roop Nagar
            [Phone] => 9837464231
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 11
            [TableNumber] => z
            [Capacity] => 10
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 1
            [Name] => Aww Bar
            [OutletID] => 2
            [Address] => Prem Bhavan
            [Phone] => 8461232871
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 4
            [TableNumber] => 1
            [Capacity] => 4
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 1
            [Name] => Aww Bar
            [OutletID] => 2
            [Address] => Prem Bhavan
            [Phone] => 8461232871
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 5
            [TableNumber] => 2
            [Capacity] => 4
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 1
            [Name] => Aww Bar
            [OutletID] => 2
            [Address] => Prem Bhavan
            [Phone] => 8461232871
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 6
            [TableNumber] => 3
            [Capacity] => 6
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 2
            [Name] => Disco Deewaane
            [OutletID] => 3
            [Address] => Gali Number 420
            [Phone] => 8372313874
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 7
            [TableNumber] => 1
            [Capacity] => 6
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 2
            [Name] => Disco Deewaane
            [OutletID] => 3
            [Address] => Gali Number 420
            [Phone] => 8372313874
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 8
            [TableNumber] => 2
            [Capacity] => 6
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 2
            [Name] => Disco Deewaane
            [OutletID] => 3
            [Address] => Gali Number 420
            [Phone] => 8372313874
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 9
            [TableNumber] => 3
            [Capacity] => 4
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 2
            [Name] => Disco Deewaane
            [OutletID] => 3
            [Address] => Gali Number 420
            [Phone] => 8372313874
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 10
            [TableNumber] => 4
            [Capacity] => 5
            [Smoking] => 1
            [Available] => 1
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 2
            [Name] => Decibel Disc
            [OutletID] => 
            [Address] => Excuse Me Please
            [Phone] => 9833346521
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 
            [TableNumber] => 
            [Capacity] => 
            [Smoking] => 
            [Available] => 
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 3
            [Name] => Disc Dec
            [OutletID] => 
            [Address] => Roop Nagar
            [Phone] => 8375643111
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 
            [TableNumber] => 
            [Capacity] => 
            [Smoking] => 
            [Available] => 
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 4
            [Name] => Bass Down Low
            [OutletID] => 
            [Address] => Prem Bhavan
            [Phone] => 9988843511
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 
            [TableNumber] => 
            [Capacity] => 
            [Smoking] => 
            [Available] => 
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 4
            [Name] => Baby ka Bass Bar
            [OutletID] => 
            [Address] => Gali Number 420
            [Phone] => 8883741234
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 
            [TableNumber] => 
            [Capacity] => 
            [Smoking] => 
            [Available] => 
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RestaurantID] => 4
            [Name] => Basswaala Bar
            [OutletID] => 
            [Address] => Excuse Me Please
            [Phone] => 9993741236,8843621439
            [Latitude] => 0
            [Longitude] => 0
            [TableID] => 
            [TableNumber] => 
            [Capacity] => 
            [Smoking] => 
            [Available] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Sorry! Query is correct but generates incorrect results!! _Does not compute! Logic bomb planted_

Comment: Can you show us how this array that you say is wrong is created please. This might be quite relevant

Comment: Does this prove that The Matrix is real?

Seriously though, I am at a loss on how to debug this. The query obtained from $this->db->get_compiled_select(), when used in $this->db->query() generates results different from $this->db->get()!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in your screenshot that there are two `OutletID` columns, one of which is `NULL` from the 11th result onwards.

My guess is that, since the result in CI is an associative array, the last occurence of `OutletID` (in this case, `NULL`) is stored.

I'd recommend not using `SELECT *` but something along the lines of :

```
SELECT Restaurant.RestaurantID AS "RestaurantID", [...],
       Outlet.OutletID AS "OutletID", [...],
       OutletTable.OutletID AS "OutletID2", [...]
```

Comment: You are The Chosen One! Lesson learnt - The more frustrating the error, the more likely it is a mundane issue I overlooked and not a bonafide bug in the framework. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember, even though it seems easier, it is almost never a good practice to use `SELECT *` in a query with `JOIN` and it can be dramatic if some of your columns in separate tables have the same name. I always try to add a suffix corresponding to the name of a table in each of its columns, like `OutletID_outlet` and `OutletID_outletTable` in your case ;)