# Best Free MySQL Profiler in 2017

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, optimization, windows-7-x64

I'm currently developing an asp.net application and it is slow.
I just want to find out if it is making unnecessary multiple db calls.

What is the best free mysql profiler?

[I know this question will likely be closed for 'off-topic' reason]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find mysql.general_log to be helpful.

To enable general logging, execute this in mysql commandline client:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Then query mysql.general_log table:

```
select * from mysql.general_log limit 1000;
```

as descibed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678310/7634575)

Answer (score 1):

"Unnecessary" calls is far too complex a question to begin to answer.

The SlowLog will tell you which types of queries are the biggest burden on the server; those are the first to consider rewriting/indexing/removing/consolidating/etc.  Hence, I see this as a possible alternative.

Some 3rd party software tends to do a lot of `SHOWs` and other junk.  But removing such would require a redesign of their software.