# How to retrieve the SQL query generated by wp_list_categories function in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How can I retrieve the actual SQL query generated by the function `wp_list_categories()` in WordPress?

I have created a custom post type and custom taxonomy (associated this with my custom taxonomy).

I have following code for retrieving a list of items from my taxonomy:

```
$args = array('taxonomy' => 'movies_taxonomy',
    'depth' => 1,
    'exclude' => 16,
    'echo' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'show_count' => 1,
    'title_li' => '');

echo wp_list_categories($args);
```

The above argument is giving me wrong result. So I want to see what exact query it is sending to the database for fetching records.

How can I get that?

Comment: try to dump $wpdb last query after call of `wp_list_categories()`

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql