# Getting the name of the columns added by artisan Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-5.5

I run the Artisan command in the code like

`Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => 'database/migrations/core']);`

I Need to know the columns added by that batch of migration which ran recently. I tried using `Artisan::output();` command but it returns the migration name alone.

Is there any way to get the column names of the migration batch or to extract the column name from the migration name?

Comment: This is not functionality provided out of the box. What you're looking for is probably something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Comment: Alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the Laravel query log:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => 'database/migrations/core']);
$log = DB::getQueryLog();
dd($log);
```