# How can i get a list of queries and their execution count

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I want to get a list of queries executed against my mysql instance, I also want to get list of executions counts for them and duration,

I can get these stats in something like datadog APM, but I would like to be able to run a query for them locally.

is there a table or schema I need to look at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Turn on the "general log" and have it write to a file.
2. Wait a finite amount of time.
3. Then use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the results.
4. Turn off the general log before it fills up disk.

The slowlog (with a small value in `long_query_time`) is more useful for finding naughty queries.