# Is it possible to see all executed query for a particular table MySQL 8.x Server

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Is it possible to turn on the history of a particular table that are being executed in MySql 8.x?. I need it to monitor a particular table particularly delete and updated statement.

Please help, thanks in Advance.

Comment: May be this link will help you out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql

Comment: For queries which alters table's data - create BEFORE triggers pack. Query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST and store current query text into service logtable. For SELECT queries - only General Log may help.

Comment: @ZeeshanZubair  the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql )is for the whole schema not for a particular table.