# How to count number of queries which sent to MySQL database in period of time?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible that can count number of queries which send to the MySQL database, during a specific time?

for example I want to know how many queries was called by using PHP in last month?
I know that we can write a program for doing this. foe example by putting this top of a PHP file

```
show session status like "Queries";
```

but I want to know does MySQL has this feature?
for example a recorded data that counts queries, and when you select a date, it shows number of queries which sent to the MySQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Comment: @Justinas you are missing the point OP is asking about count of queries that has been executed over a period of time.

Comment: You could analyze the mysql logs.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh No, I don't. There is plenty of answers about where to look for queries logs