# How to output SQL queries from Yii2 migrations before running them?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yii, yii2

Is there any tool or programming technique to capture the output from Yii2 migrations to up/down SQL scripts, that is, print the migration corresponding raw SQL before finally running `php yii migrate`?

For example, [in Laravel](https://www.amitmerchant.com/dry-running-laravel-migrations-before-actually-migrating-them/) you can add a flag `--pretend` to output the queries to the terminal, like in `php artisan migrate --pretend`. Is there anything similar in Yii Framework?

Comment: There is no way of doing it out-of-the-box in Yii 2 (you can only log queries prior to the execution) but it gives me a nice idea of a new feature in my package https://github.com/bizley/yii2-migration :) thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/bizley/yii2-migration ready with that feature ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install [Bizley's migration package](http://github.com/bizley/yii2-migration) and try `php yii migration/sql m220914_000000_create_clients_table` for example, and the corresponding SQL statements can be extracted, like:

```
$ php yii migration/sql m220914_000001_create_client_member_levels_table
Yii 2 Migration Generator Tool v4.4.0
 > SQL statements of the m220914_000001_create_client_member_levels_table file (UP method):

CREATE TABLE `client_member_levels` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `level_identifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'employee',
    `display_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Employee',
    `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    `updated_at` datetime(0),
    `deleted_at` datetime(0)
);
ALTER TABLE `client_member_levels` ADD INDEX `idx-client_member_levels-client_id` (`client_id`);
ALTER TABLE `client_member_levels` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk-client_member_levels-client_id` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`client_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

 (!) Note that the above statements were not executed.

$
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bizley said when commenting the question, there is not a native way of doing it for Yii2 until the moment this question was answered.

For my case [I just tracked my MySQL DB log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql) and picked the queries I was looking for, since I had to set the current DB into a new one through migrations.