# how to view all the queries that are being performed on my web app

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mac with snow leopard and i have sequel pro and im trying to figure out how i can view all the queries that are being done on my web site so that i can track down the problem. how can i do this? on sequel pro there is a console that i can click on and all it shows me are the selects being done so when i do a delete it doesnt show that. would this information be somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open /etc/my.cnf or create it if it does not already exist. Add or uncomment the line `log=/var/log/mysqld.log` in the `[mysqld]` section.

Create the logfile with `sudo touch /var/log/mysqld.log` and make it writeable for the mysql user with `sudo chown _mysqld /var/log/mysqld.log`. Note that you'll may have to replace `_mysql`!

Now restart MySQL and view the log with `tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log` or in console app.

Comment: where is the etc directory ? is it in mamp somewhere i cant find it.

Comment: Apparently MAMP doesn't use my.cnf, but you can create one and append your settings: http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6306

Answer (score 1):

To view live queries run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.
Note, that you should run this from a user that has [PROCESS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) permissions.

Alternatively, you can log all queries that mysql processes, by setting `log = all.log` in the my.ini file.

Also see this question: [Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql)

Comment: i dont seem to have my.ini i use mamp for mac and im trying to figure out where this is or how to do it. any clue?