# WordPress Meta Data Being Corrupted, Deleted, or Altered

Tags: wordpress

I've got a single meta variable with a string value that should always be 0 or 1 being stored on pages. I can set it using a simple dropdown box in a metabox and it seems to work great. For some bizarre reason, it sometimes gets changed from 1 to 0 seemingly randomly. I have no clue why, and it seems to happen even on a page I wasn't editing or updating. I'm baffled and don't even know where to begin looking because I haven't figured out how to replicate the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions to search for a possible way to replicate this or figure out the cause?

Comment: You only need to debug, POST data and catch values exactly before to be saved to DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO: That kind of bugs only can be catch debugging. Exists a tool called [mtop](http://mtop.sourceforge.net/) that allows you see at all DB actions...

[image]

**UPDATE**

More easy is to log all queries in a period of time (until you see the malfunction) Here a related issue: [Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql). Then you only need to look closer at `update` actions in the appropriate table. This can be done in windows or *nix. Good luck...

Comment: You are awesome, Nomik!  Thank you!  The query logging suggestion is going to work perfectly, because the bug happens so rarely.  But I didn't know about mtop so that's extremely helpful!  Installing it now. :)