# Is there any way to find who is deleted database from Phpmyadmin which is hosted on linux server

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

We have a centralized linux server on which phpmyadmin is installed and someone is continuously deleting the database, so I would like to track the activities done in phpmyadmin as well as in linux server so please help me how this can be achieved

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just have to check your log file.
Here how to log all queries in mysql

[Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if the database is dropped from the phpmyadmin then how to track that , I m interested in tracking that !
not sure if its possible!!!