# Get a list of all executed queries in a time frame

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in MySQL that I can get a list of all the UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT queries executed in last 1 hour? I want to do this for a sync functionality where I'll get this list at Server1 and pass to Server2 which will then execute all these and get sync'd.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn on mysql log on server to store all queries executed on it.

[Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql)