# How can I see the exact queries phpmyadmin is running?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I see what SQL queries phpmyadmin runs to execute commands? I want to create a not easy database, first using phpmyadmin, then using php code. But when I create the table with phpmyadmin, it doesn't show the commands it uses to create or select a table.

Is there any way? :)

Thanks!

ps.: mysql version: 5.6.12

Comment: Just export the table after creating it.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin shows SQL queries it has run just after they completed in green / red boxed depending on their results. Execute some queries and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your `my.cnf` file and add this line:

```
log=/var/log/mysql.log
```

Next you can monitor that file using tail with this command:

```
tail -f var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

And you will see all queries on real time :)

Comment: I've got a wild guess that the OP is using windows...

Comment: Erm, a question. Where is the "my.cnf" file? That is the mysql consol? Or what?

Comment: So you are runing windows? should be in the same folder where your mysql server executable file is. Are you using wamp?

Answer (score 0):

This question is perhaps already answered in older Stack Overflow questions [Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql) or [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)

(I used Google "mysql query logger" to find them)