# How to see full mysql query that my script send to xammp local server?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have an error in my script and want to see full mysql query but mysql error log don't show any queryies that my script send. 
I changed my.ini file and add

```
general_log = 1
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = "C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql-slow.log"
```

I found this in slow-query.log file

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe, Version: 5.6.21-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

But how to see full query of my script? Thanx in advance!

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer this question.  What database library are you using, MySQLI? PDO? How are you constructing the query, with string concatenation? With prepared statements?  What is the query you're trying to run? Does the query work properly when you execute it directly on the SQL server?

Comment: I hope this link will help you.

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62129/how-to-log-all-mysql-queries-into-log-file

Comment: Refer these 2 links.Hope you'll get your answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6479107/1179841

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/303994/1179841

Answer (score 0):

To see all queries, not only the slow ones, you have to specify also `general_log_file`:

```
general_log=1
general_log_file="C:/xampp/mysql/data/query.log"
```

And then restart mysql server.