# List the blogs which has published and approved by admin in concrete5

Tags: mysql, pdo, concrete5, magento-1.9.1

How do I write mysql queries in magento to get blog data from the concrete5 db? I wish to see blogs which are in published status in concrete5.

```
SELECT content FROM btContentLocal WHERE bID = 85
```

This query retrieves a single page but I want to get all the published blogs/pages. How can I do that?

Comment: This is going to be a very complex query as concrete5 uses many joins to gather information about a page. It might help to set up a page list that is filtered the way you want it, then watch what queries are made in mysql.

Comment: How can i do it with the page list  object?

Comment: Make a pagelist and run the `->get` method, at the same time watch what queries come in in mysql. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql