# Detecting unauthorized queries to a WordPress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I suspect that an ex-employee, who had ftp and backend access to our WordPress site, created and installed an API to allow smartphone access to our database.  How can I detect queries being made to the database and see what is requesting them?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just change passwords?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log all MySQL (just a guess) queries you can go with the solution in this post: [Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql)

But it should be mentioned that this is not wise for a production site.

Besides, if you really expect that he could have altered the installation with malicious code you should either reinstall a fresh wordpress and transfer all data or at least validate the code files against a fresh wordpress installation to check for altered code.
Basically this is the same as for a potentially penetrated system, restart at a backup point that you trust or with a fresh copy.

Comment: You say "validate files against a fresh wordpress installation."  Is there something that will compare two wordpress installations and report the differences?

Comment: On Linux a simple way to compare two directories would be:
`diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/`.
Since the wp-content directory will contain a lot of custom data you have to do some manual work to check that. Maybe compare it with an old backup.