# Wordpress Query SUM() giving wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been scratching my head on this and have done some google searches but can't figure out why this query returns the wrong SUM.

```
$points = $wpdb->get_results("Select SUM(points) as points from $sc WHERE division_id = '$divid' and participant_id = '$partid' and status = '1'");
```

If I go to the database and run just the following, it will work perfectly exactly how I need it to. But if I put it in the Wordpress Query Get_Results format, it returns wrong information.

```
Select SUM(points) as points from $sc WHERE division_id = '$divid' and participant_id = '$partid' and status = '1'
```

What am I Missing, does Wordpress utilize SUM differently?

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql to log all sql queries. Once, you make changes, run the above sql from your wordpress app and check if you see the exact query being fired to database.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I can copy and past the query and get a different result from the database then from what is shown in logging the results. I am completely confused :)

Comment: So, are you seeing different results for the same query in sql logs?

Comment: That is correct. If I run the query from the logs in MySQL outside of the app I get 6, but when I display query results in the logs I get 2

Comment: Can you paste both the queries and their outputs please? Though they are different, I want both the queries