# str_replace on string on foreach array

Tags: php, arrays

I'am trying to replace a part of a string for another value and i'am doing this for some logs that i need to create, to have the full query. I'am using PDO.

I want to in the end have the correct query to print on the log.

```
    public function queryBindValues($string,$data,$queriesLog) {
    echo gettype($data); //object
    $toArray = (array)$data; //convert to array
    $finalArray = [];

    //remove class name(on key) from array
    foreach($toArray as $k=>$v) {
      $k = str_replace(get_class($data), "", $k);
      $finalArray[$k] = $v;
    }

    /*
    $finalArray
      Array
      (
          [id] => 
          [gender] => vbn
          [status] => 1
          [user_id] => TLDICA
          [last_update] => 2018-04-25
      )
    */

    //string = INSERT INTO type_genders (status, user_id, last_update, gender) VALUES (:status, :user_id, :last_update, :gender);

    foreach($finalArray as $k=>$v) {
      $string = str_replace(":$k", $v, $string);
    }

    echo $string;
    //INSERT INTO type_genders (status, user_id, last_update, gender) VALUES (:status, :user_id, :last_update, :gender)
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks,

Comment: what does that mean? `$string = str_replace(":$k", $v, $string);`, you're replacing placeholders into the values? i don't understand what are you trying to accomplish here

Comment: I'am replacing :status by 1, for example.

Comment: just make sure `$string` does really have those placeholders, looking on this side it would work just fine, my advice to you also is to log the queries made this way instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/304008/3859027

Comment: cannot log like that, i'am using PDO, bindvalues. you don't get the complete query.

Comment: oh okay, yeah you cannot get the logged query if its being prepared, anyway, the problem is elsewhere, since you have the correct `$string` with the correct value, [it will work just fine](https://3v4l.org/IfKvG), like what i've said earlier, you need to debug some more,

Comment: yes, same code, but for some reason it doesnt work. thanks anyway.

Comment: found the problem, it is on the array. if i create manually the array it works. but if i convert from object to array, doesn't work.

Comment: good for you then, that's why on the link i provided, if the given inputs are correct, the code should work just fine. we just don't know (on our end) what the original `$data` looks like

Comment: $data looks like this:
       TypeGenders Object
(
    [id:TypeGenders:private] => 
    [gender:TypeGenders:private] => w
    [status:TypeGenders:private] => 1
    [user_id:TypeGenders:private] => TLDICA
    [last_update:TypeGenders:private] => 2018-04-25
)