# Debug doctrine master/slave queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using a master/slave connection with Doctrine in my Symfony Application

The configuration is really basic, with one master and one slave

I have problems between master and slave (replica lags) in my app, and I want debug that.

When I do a `tail -f app/logs/dev/dev-2018-05-15.log` I can see all `doctrine.DEBUG` queries, but only the SQL.

Is there a way to see which query is performed on which slave/master?

Comment: I hope that this can help you [log sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes, I did that, but I was wondering if something existed in Symfony/Doctrine to get it directly inside the Symfony logs

Answer (score -1):

I think that monolog can help you : 
see this [monolog doctrine](https://www.remipoignon.fr/10-symfony-2-configuration-des-logs-monolog)