# Log mysql insert update queries

Tags: mysql, sql

How can we only log the complete list of insert and update queries executed in mysql

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html check out this.

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql

Comment: I have these configurations. But it generates all queries. I want to only log INSERT and UPDATE queries. Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Start mysql with the --log option:

mysqld --log=log_file_name
or place the following in your my.cnf file:

log = log_file_name
Either one will log all queries to log_file_name.

You can also log only slow queries using the --log-slow-queries option instead of --log. By default, queries that take 10 seconds or longer are considered slow, you can change this by setting long_query_time to the number of seconds a query must take to execute before being logged.

Comment: Can you explain which part of this configuration specifies only to log insert and update queries.