# Find intensive queries/pages sitewide with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My website is build with Laravel and for the most part, works perfectly fine. However, there is an occasional issue where the website comes to a complete stop and page loading takes almost 5+ minutes. I have had this issue previously and it was because there was page on the website that was performing a loop of thousands and thousands of queries depending on what the user inputted into a form. If the user entered the number 5,000 then the page would perform 5,000 queries. Once I fixed that then everything was working perfectly again. I have my suspicion that something similar has happened again however I'm having trouble pinpointing exactly what could be causing it.

Is there anything that I can do, site-wise, to monitor this and help me locate the issue? Perhaps there is something that can be done on the operating system itself (I'm using Ubuntu)? It would be great if there was some monitoring system that allowed me to see which pages took the longest to complete all of its queries to the database.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a tool like that in phpMyAdmin Status/Monitor

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql

Comment: I have used that previously but it's no help as I need something for production if possible. I want to know what queries are run from the users that visit the website.

Comment: you could try to use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to get all the queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track all queries/events/errors for all users with traces etc. then maybe

[Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/telescope)

is what you want. It is an UI for inspecting and debugging everything in Laravel. If your Laravel version is above 5.7.7 you can install it right away

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you. Do you think this cause any problems if used on production?

Comment: It is used by a lot of folks in production, the only thing is, that it can ramp up the database quite quickly, but how to handle this is described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/telescope#data-pruning), so really a non issue :)