# Magento 2 emptying CMS page table?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

This is a very peculiar problem. A client's Magento 2.2.6 EE has emptied its cms page table twice today (sometime between 5pm EST and 5:20pm and again between 11:00pm and 11:30pm). I have disabled magento's crontab until a solution presents itself. The action log also has no records of access.

I combed through the action logs but nothing there stood out.

Has anyone come across this before? And how would I debug this? The system is setup to make hourly db snapshots so it's just a headache at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Way interesting. I would start logging your db calls to find when and how the tables are emptied.

Check out [this StackOverflow answer using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql).

If you get the exact query and user info, if Magento system user, search your whole install for that query reference.

Another option, if you have Magento plugins, disable all and see if the issue presents itself again.

Does the index reset when the table is emptied? If so, try disable truncate permissions from the Magento user and see what error is thrown when this action is attempted again. This would be a way to find the source of the call using the Magento error log.