# File Location of a mysql logfile

Tags: mysql

I've got a question to this discussion:
[Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql)

Under answer ten is written:
mysqld --log=log_file_name

1. Can I give the name "mysql_result.txt" for the logfile?
2. Where is the location of mysql_result.txt?

The folder of MySQL is /etc/mysql under ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please note: the MySQL folder is /var/lib/mysql under Ubuntu. /etc/mysql contains only configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

IF you give absolute path, you wont have any issue about where it is going to be saved. If you use relative path, It is saved **under the data directory** of the mysql server instance

Answer (score 0):

is the following sql-statemant correct, if i will safe the file on my desktop in ubuntu:

mysqld --log=/home/mike/Schreibtisch/mysql_result.txt

Thanks a lot

MB

Comment: Only if the directory is writable by the mysql user. I would suggest creating a directory under /tmp, home directories tend to protect user data from other users.