# How do I get a list of every MySQL query on a server with a corresponding time stamp?#

Tags: mysql

I have a web application that is crashing at certain intervals. The standard logs are not giving enough information, so I would like to have a log of every MySQL query so I can look at the time stamp and see what query(ies) was(were) running at the time of the crash.

I was unable to find any results in search for how to do this. Can anyone explain how to enable this type of log?

Comment: This question belongs on dba.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is for questions about specific code problems, but this question is more about MySQL Server configuration.

Comment: The short answer: read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: follow this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql

Comment: The Slow Query Log records queries when they FINISH with system time which might get you close enough to the real problem.  That log is easy, just SET LONG_QUERY_TIME=0;  (from a MySQL Command Prompt) and every query will be logged before the instance crashes.  If this does not have you covered, what do you mean by 'certain intervals'?

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck I'll try this and see if it's sufficient for my needs and then you can repost as an Answer and I'll mark it as completed.

Comment: @SpencerHill Thanks, Spencer.  Have a great weekend.  Will be OOO for a few days.